# SRC variable with list

Tags: javascript, list, src

I want create my own calendar for my job. In this calendar i have some information the MJD (Modified Julian Day), the GPS weeks and the DOY (Day of years), so i can't copy past the code of calendar find on the net.

I have create some month (2 for the start) and i want to choose the month and the years with list and the calendar is autmaticly change.

i have build like this :

```
  <ul>
    <li class="prev">&#10094;</li>
    <li class="next">&#10095;</li>

            <div class="calendarItem">
                <p>
                    <select name="Month" id="Month">
    <option value="Jan">January</option>
    <option value="Feb">February</option>
    <option value="March">March</option>
    <option value="April">April</option>
    <option value="May">May</option>
    <option value="June">June</option>
    <option value="July">July</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="August">August</option>
    <option value="September">September</option>
    <option value="October">October</option>
    <option value="November">November</option>
    <option value="December">December</option>

</select>
                    &nbsp;
                    <select name="Year" id="Year">
    <option value="1998">1998</option>
    <option value="1999">1999</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="2001">2001</option>
    <option value="2002">2002</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2003">2003</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>

</select>
                    &nbsp;
<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Go To Month" id="Button1" onclick="create_path()" />

<script>
function create_path()
{
    var test = "test";
    var mois = document.getElementById("Month").value;
    var année = document.getElementById("Year").value;
    var path=mois+'_'+année+".js";
    alert(path);
    document.write("<script src='"+path+"'/>");
}
</script>

</script>
```

and Jan_2020.js is like this :

```
document.write("      Janvier<br>");
document.write("      <span style='font-size:18px'>2020</span>");
document.write("    </li>");
document.write("  </ul>");
document.write("</div>");

    
    
document.write("<ul class='weekdays' >");
document.write("  <li>Mo</li>");
document.write("  <li>Tu</li>");
document.write("  <li>We</li>");
document.write("  <li>Th</li>");
document.write("  <li>Fr</li>");
document.write("  <li>Sa</li>");
document.write("  <li>Su</li>");
document.write("</ul>");

document.write("<ul class='days'>  >");
document.write("  <li></li>");
document.write("  <li></li>");
document.write("  <b><li style='color:black'>1<br><span style='color:red'>MJD: 58849<br><span style='color:blue'>DOY: 1<br><span style='color:green'>GPS Weeks : 38<br></li>");
document.write("  <li style='color:black'>2<br><span style='color:red'>MJD: 58850<br><span style='color:blue'>DOY: 2<br><span style='color:green'>GPS Weeks : 38<br></li>");
document.write("  <li style='color:black'>3<br><span style='color:red'>MJD: 58851<br><span style='color:blue'>DOY: 3<br><span style='color:green'>GPS Weeks : 38<br></li>");
document.write("  <li style='color:black'>4<br><span style='color:red'>MJD: 58852<br><span style='color:blue'>DOY: 4<br><span style='color:green'>GPS Weeks : 38<br></li>");
[...]
document.write("</ul>");
```

i know this things doesn't work. but i can't find the solution.. i am novice in JS.

I would like something like this website (but with the information i needed)

http://navigationservices.agi.com/GNSSWeb/

Comment: So you want to create a file for each month for 2020 and if you select the month load your month file?

Comment: Yes. But the tab of each month is created in advence

Comment: I don't find the solution.. Nobody can help me ?

Comment: `const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = '/my/script/file.js';
document.head.append(script);` Does this help maybe?

Comment: I have try, but i don't know how use this code.